# RoR: Could not load OpenSSL (after Apple's Bash fix today)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash, shellshock-bash-bug

Hoping someone can help explain and or advise me on this error I'm catching after i tried to re-install rails via rvm after running Apple's bash shellshock fix today.
I upgraded to OSX 10.9.5 mav and ran the Bash Shellshock, then my RoR apps needed rails re-installed.  When I try to bundle install I get the following:

Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for
compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Ruby version you installed with RVM

```
$ rvm remove ruby-2.1.2
```

and reinstall it

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.1.2
```

Comment: Hi Simone, I just did what you told me and when I tried running rails s the following occured:   /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
 from /Users/mysuername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'

Comment: Any ideas from here?  Thanks for your time really.